# TypeError: Cannot read property 'unlockAccount' of undefined

Tags: web3js

I have included all required modules while starting Geth:

```
instance: Geth/v1.9.9-stable-01744997/linux-amd64/go1.13.4

coinbase: 0x5c56bf111b3f894efae992e34a7be5be38950399

at block: 3078 (Mon, 06 Jan 2020 17:23:04 IST)
 datadir: /home/sama/Desktop/Navjeet/ethereum-private/Network/ethdata
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 ethash:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

Theese are the  personal methods provived by web3:

```
personal: 
      Personal {
        currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
        _requestManager: [Object],
        givenProvider: null,
        providers: [Object],
        _provider: [Object],
        setProvider: [Function],
        BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
        extend: [Object],
        net: [Object],
        defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
        defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
        getAccounts: [Object],
        newAccount: [Object],
        unlockAccount: [Object],
        lockAccount: [Object],
        importRawKey: [Object],
        sendTransaction: [Object],
        signTransaction: [Object],
        sign: [Object],
        ecRecover: [Object] },
```

Still Not able to unlock account from node using web3 and also not able to create account using web3.personal.newAccount. I am ble to create new account using web3.eth.accounts.create(),but it is not showing in Geth console.I am using web3 version 1.2.4.  Please help.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What is the command line used to launche geth?

Comment: This is the command i have used to start geth console:

geth --datadir ethdata --networkid 123 --ipcdisable --port 4321 --rpcport 8543  --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover console --rpcapi="eth,net,web3,personal,web3"

Comment: Tis is the code :
   web3.personal.unlockAccount(sender, pass, 600)
  .then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
  });